# C# Close child form if it lost focus but not if application is not active

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

How can I close the dialog (form) when it loses its activity (focus), but not close if you switch to another application, desktop and etc?

So far i use this code:

`private void MyDialog_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Close();
}`

Comment: why is the dialog losing focus.. why not show it as modal so that you do not lose focus..?

Comment: That's just doesn't make any sense.  A dialog disables all other windows in your application.  So the user can only ever switch to a window in another application.  It already works the way you want it.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thing is, that it must be closed if click inside parent window.

Comment: @Yura as Hans stated, you cannot click inside parent window, when you have dialog window opened

Comment: @HansPassant In my case dialog is a windows form that called from parent form. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: That's how all dialogs work.  It is not me that's confused.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll try to explain. 1. Create winform app. 2 Put button on form, add event to show second form.3 If you click on first form, second form immediately closing.4 If you click on desktop two windows become inactive. With possibility to click on first form that cause step 3. Thats it.

Comment: Dialog usually means modal, which means it cannot lose focus.  Are you doing a `Show()` or a `ShowDialog()` on these other forms you call Dialog?

Comment: @LarsTech I'm doing `Show ()` for this form. But it does not matter to me whether a form is modal. I just need that logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your use of the word *dialog* is confusing, since that usually implies a modal form.

Based on your description, I think you can just close the open forms based on the main form getting activated:

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnActivated(e);

  List<Form> closeForms = new List<Form>();
  foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms) {
    if (!f.Equals(this)) {
      closeForms.Add(f);
    }
  }

  foreach (Form f in closeForms) {
    f.Dispose();
  }
}
```